# Kafka Connect Logstash

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash

How to Connect with Logstash via Apache Kafka?
the question how to get it out of Kafka and into something like Elasticsearch inevitably comes up.
Does any one has a tuto to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Logstash has an input plugin for Kafka. First of all, you should getting familiar with Apache Kafka and its **producer/consumer** paradigm: https://kafka.apache.org/.

Then getting started with Logstash: https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash. After all of this, you will be able to use Kafka input plugin for logstash:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-kafka.html.

The last step is build a logstash pipeline to insert data into a destination like Elasticsearch. This simple example can help you to achieve your goal:

**logstash.conf**

```
input {  
    kafka {
        bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
        topics => ["example-topic"]
    }
}

output {  
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
        index => "example-index"
    }
}
```

Here we simply take data coming from kafka queue on a specific topic. Then we store the data into an elasticsearch index. Hope that helps!

Comment: Good answer.Where should we use kafka ideally?Before logstash or after logstash?

Comment: I don't clearly understand what you mean but, as per my understanding, there is no ideal place for that. Logstash can ingest data from kafka as well as send them in a kafka queue. So it can be placed before or after Logstash in a pipeline.

Comment: Its pretty frequently used both in front of and behind kafka, using log stash to send data to kafka (with a logstash "shipper" instance) then another instance ("consumer") to read from kafka and send off to another place from there. The idea being the "shipper" should be as light weight as possible to handle high volume where the "consumer" is more resource intensive since it is (or should be) doing some kind of filtering/transformation. 

More reading at https://www.elastic.co/blog/just-enough-kafka-for-the-elastic-stack-part1